# A smarter way to categorize by keywords?

Tags: database, data-mining, categorization

Our site has user-generated content and a user can use hashtags to categories their content.  To make searching for content easier, we are thinking about creating "Interest" categories like:

```
Sex, Hobbies, Current Events, etc.
```

One way to achieve this would be to associate keywords with each interest category.  So, if a user clicks on Hobbies, the system will search for the keywords we've associated with Hobbies like:

```
Hobbies -> cars, cooking, reading, etc.
```

However, this method seems limited since a user can post a picture of a hotrod with the words "sexy" in the body and with our system the word "sexy" is associated with two interest categories: "Sex" and "Fashion & Beauty".

Any suggestions on how to make this method smarter?  Or, suggestions/advice on how companies would implement something like this?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good SO questions.  Hint: this is not a coding question, so it is "not constructive" on SO.

Comment: @JimGarrison Disagree, as the (linked) FAQ says: a **specific programming problem**, **a software algorithm** is also welcome in SO.

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227704/how-to-effectively-implement-an-algorithm) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423246/including-posts-that-users-have-commented-on) question I noticed that you used the approach I recommended below. So, you could accept my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should **weight the categories**. Find all the matching words, and assign a value to all categories as follows:

- Add 3 for every word that is undoubtfully belongs to that category
- Add 1 for every word that may belong to more categories

It is a biased weighting (towards unique words), this way you can better decide where the pictures belong to.

Also, you can build a - **continuously changing** - weight-matrix, that which word is how relevant to a certain category. The frequent words bear less importance (because everybody is using them).

Also, based on the categorized texts, you can **automatically extend** the word-list, and automatically categorizing them. For example, if a new game name appears in the word-list (call it 'abc'), you will notice that 'abc' appears in a lot of texts in the *hobby* category, *and nowhere else*. So, you can tie this word to this category.

It's a very exciting area to build auto-learning systems!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I can't help but think that my proposed solution, even with your suggestions, will make for a very labor intensive solution as I imaging a person having to always update the keyword list for each interest. Would you agree?  Is what you are proposing a typical solution or are there more sophisticated ways.

Comment: Not exactly. I missed one thing: **the pictures must be categorised** at upload time (for the current stock, you can do it offline). You can search for the categories only, not for the words (which is way faster method). The administrator has no tasks, everything goes on the way. First, you index all words, and count that in which categories they appear, and how many times. This will give you a frequency matrix. Based on that, you calculate the **importance matrix**, which you will use when a new pic is uploaded. The key is, how you calculate the importance.

Comment: Is this answer satisfying?

Comment: I don't really understand why the pictures need to be categorized.  Also, wouldn't assigning a value to each word require a lot of labor?  We could potentially have thousands of keywords.

Comment: The main reason why pictures need to be categorized is this: `If a user clicks on Hobbies, the system will search for the keywords`. So, searching is done like "find the words that belong to a category, and find all the words in all texts". That's **really time-consuming**, and unnecessary, because all these things are **static** - don't change by time. So, you can do it **once, when uploading**. To your second question: The main thing with assigning is that **you don't have to do it manually**. You are a programmer, write an algorithm for that.