# How to effectively implement an algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, gearman

We've recently worked with a mathematician to build us an algorithm.  The algorithm will look at click data and will continuously update data associated with the user, the content, and the content's category and then pair the user with relevant content.

With that said, I have never implemented an algorithm before but I'm guessing that our current environment (PHP, MySQL) is not entirely suitable for continuously crunching and updating data.

**Can anyone give me feedback on whether the following approach is on the right track?**

- Write algorithm in java (or other compiled language) for best performance
- Store user, content, and category data on a NoSQL server (or use memcache)
- Use Gearman (or equivalent) to submit click/user data to a job server
- Run jobs on separate worker server that contains the algorithm
- Update user, content, category data

**Can you recommend articles that explain how to implement algorithms most efficiently?**

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you need someone to write the code for you or you need someone to use Google it for you?

Comment: This is better probably better suited for [programmers.SE]

Comment: @Mihailorga - Neither. I just would like to know if the way I am architecting the implementation of the algorithm is on the right track. I am not a programmer, per se, so I don't care about the code and I was unable to find something useful on google (probably because I wasn't using the right keywords).  Perhaps you can comment on what keywords I should search for?