# Including posts that users have commented on

Tags: mysql, sql

I am calculating average points for users that authored a post.  However, now I want to average in the points for the posts that they commented on too.  My query, without including comments looks like this:

```
SELECT u.user_fullname, ROUND(AVG(p.total_points),2) avgPoints
FROM cl_user_identities u
JOIN cl_posts p ON p.user_identity_id = u.user_identity_id
GROUP BY u.user_identity_id
```

How do I add in the posts that users have commented on too?

Here is my table schema:

```
cl_posts
 - post_id
 - user_identity_id
 - post_title
 - total_points

cl_comments
 - comment_id
 - post_id
 - user_identity_id
 - comment_text

cl_user_identities
 - user_identity_id
 - user_fullname
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: It would help if you included your table schema.

Comment: @hugo . . . That's a really good question.  How do you know if a user commented on a post?

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin - Sorry about that.  I added the schema above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_fullname, 
 ROUND(AVG(p.total_points),2) avgPoints,
 (SELECT ROUND(AVG(total_points),2) FROM cl_posts p2 JOIN cl_comments c2 ON c2.post_id = p2.post_id WHERE c2.user_identity_id = u.user_identity_id) as avgPoints2
FROM cl_user_identities u
JOIN cl_posts p ON p.user_identity_id = u.user_identity_id
GROUP BY u.user_identity_id
```

Comment: If I wanted one column for avg points, would it be as simple as:((avgPoints + avgPoints2)/2)?

Comment: no you have to embed the whole thing. Either you can keep them separate and add them later, or combine like so: ROUND(AVG(p.total_points),2) + (SELECT ROUND(AVG(total_points),2) FROM cl_posts p2 JOIN cl_comments c2 ON c2.post_id = p2.post_id WHERE c2.user_identity_id = u.user_identity_id) as avgPoints